# Word for disposable cutlery etc preferably without using "disposable"

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

Is there one word (or phrase) to describe all forms of disposable cutlery etc, such as paper cups, paper napkins, paper/plastic spoons and forks, plates, etc. ?

I thought of *disposable cutlery* itself, and apart from that the common synonyms such as *tableware*, but is there one word that describes this specifically, preferably without using the word *disposable* at all?

Edit:

I appreciate the answers I have got till now, but many of the solutions are of the form *disposable < synonym of cutlery >*. While that is fine, if possible, I would prefer to have a word or phrase not containing the word *disposable*. The idea is to remove the negative connotation that might arise with the word *disposable*. Thank you.

Comment: Disposable Cutlery & Plastic Silverware

Comment: @edwin I don't quite understand why there are too many "etc." in there.

Comment: I've edited the title to match the body-question.

Comment: Side remark: you seem to be using “cutlery” to include cups, napkins, etc.  In my (mostly UK) experience this is nonstandard — cutlery covers knives, forks, spoons, and similar eating utensils, but not plates, cups, or napkins.  (And I understand “silverware” and “flatware” in US usage to cover the same range of items.)

Comment: disposable has a negative connotation because, well, it is pretty negative.

Comment: Do we not want *disposable* because we want the user to feel better about themselves or because we want to encourage multiple uses, for financial or environmental reasons?

Comment: For context could you tell us why it can't just be called tableware? Tableware already consists of many materials

Answer (score 34, accepted):

**Single-use tableware** is an option. It's something you might find at a catered event or anyplace that washing-up facilities aren't available, such as a street fair. It doesn't imply cheap - some of the stuff is quite good. You can also call it recyclable tableware if you are trying to be PC.

Single-use — [ODO](https://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/single-use)

> *adjective* Designed to be used once and then disposed of or destroyed
>   *"billions of single-use cups are thrown into landfill sites every year"*

Usage examples:

- http://www.naturaltableware.com/about-natural-tableware/
- http://www.mrtakeoutbags.com/store/dinnerware.html

Comment: This has the advantage of not using **disposable*. +1

Comment: I have edited your answer to add a definition. Hope I'm not stepping on your toes. Also, +1 :)

Answer (score 14):

<sub>*I think OP's edited question makes my answer appear odd. So, check out a better [answer by Phil Sweet](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/345321/50044).*</sub>

**Disposables** — [ODO](https://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/disposable)

> *noun* An article designed to be thrown away after use
>   *"don’t buy disposables, such as cups and plates"*

The specific meaning will be understood from context.

**Plasticware** — [Dictionary](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/plasticware)

> *noun* 1. Knives, forks, spoons, cups, etc., made of plastic
>   *"a picnic hamper with plasticware for six."*

and similarly, **paperware**, etc.

I don't know of a simpler term than **Disposable cutlery** — [TFD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Disposable+cutlery)

> utensils, as knives, forks, and spoons, used for serving and eating food.

or **disposable tableware** — [M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tableware)

> dishes, glasses, knives, forks, etc., that are used for serving and eating food at a table

Comment: **Disposable tableware** nails it, I think. +1

Comment: I think OP's edited question makes my answer appear odd. :/

Comment: @NVZ I am sorry about that, thank you for your suggestion of Plasticware and Paperware though.

Comment: In our house, we use the terms *plastic knife, plastic fork, plastic spoon* to clearly differentiate the cutlery we obtain at fast food places from the regular metal things. So *plasticware* seems good.

Answer (score 4):

**Party plates** is a synonym for paper/plastic/disposable/unbreakable plates - you could therefore go for **party tableware** but that's a bit of a mouthfull so you could say **party plates 'n' stuff**.

Are you ready for the picnic?  Who's bringing the party plates n stuff?

Comment: I like this answer.  I believe you should coin the phrase "partyware"

Answer (score 4):

"**Paper service**" seems like it might have the right meaning, so I thought I'd mention it.

I'm not sure it's the best choice–actually, I learned of this word recently in chat when someone else asked what it meant, and I had to do some Googling to find out, so it might not be widely understood. However, it does avoid the term "disposable" so that may be why some catering services use the term: it could be considered a marketing euphemism, like "bath tissue" for "toilet paper."

Here are some examples of it being used:

> Since the Student Union does not have **paper service**, you have the
>   availability to take food out of the Student Union in the following: -
>   Eco Clamshells will be available to take out food - Bring your own
>   cup: up to 32 oz [...] ([Meal Plans – Cincinnati Christian University](http://ccuniversity.edu/undergraduate/dining-services/meal-plans/))

A catering business contrasts it with "china service":

> ### Flatware Options
>
> **Standard Paper Service – included in base menu price**
>
> - 10″ Chinet paper plate, black plastic utensils, paper napkins, paper coffee cups (Silver plastic utensils – add $0.25/person)
>
> **Disposable Imitation China – $3.50/person**
>
> - 10” disposable plastic plate, disposable plastic coffee cup, silver plastic utensils, cloth-like paper napkins
>
> **Full China Service – $6.00/person (max. 150 people)**
>
> - 10″ China plate, stainless silverware, China coffee cup and saucer, linen napkins
>
> ([MJ’s Market & Catering Terms & Conditions](http://mjsmarketandcatering.com/terms-conditions/))

Another catering example:

> Continental and Hot Breakfast Buffets include a draped buffet table
>   and paper service. ([Catering Manual - Eastern New Mexico University Roswell](https://www.roswell.enmu.edu/documents/dining_services/catering_manual.pdf))

Answer (score 2):

How about just plain old "Picnicware" It implies the nature of the stuff your talking about pretty clearly to most people, without reminding them about what happens to it afterwards "whether an actual picnic or not". A psychological parry is clearly what your after here. Its close to the mark for what your trying to describe.

Comment: I don't know what most people *actually* do, but virtually all the photos of picnic baskets clearly show metal non-disposable flatware.

Answer (score 2):

It could depend on use too. This doesn't apply so much in the consumer sector, but for businesses, it would often be referred to as take-out supplies or to-go supplies and that's what it's often advertised as on websites that sell these supplies. You can see that on a few websites:

> Branded take-out supplies exponentially elevate your brand and the investment in branded plastic cups will more than pay for itself. https://budgetbranders.com/products/custom-plastic-cups/

> Declutter plastic silverware and other take out supplies. https://www.home-storage-solutions-101.com/declutter-plastic-cutlery-take-out-supplies.html

Answer (score 1):

Not one word, but how about **disposable dinnerware and flatware** or **disposable dinnerware and cutlery**?

From Merriam-Webster:

> **dinnerware**: tableware other than flatware
>
> **flatware**, **cutlery**: forks, spoons, and knives used for serving and eating food

Note: There doesn't appear to be a single word that covers both dinnerware and flatware, not to mention a single word that also includes the concept of disposability. Hence, it's not obvious one can do better than three words without inventing new words.

Note: I was wrong about there not being a single word that covers both dinnerware and flatware: **tableware** does the job. See @NVZ's answer: **disposable tableware**.

Comment: "Flatware" has different meanings in American and British English. In the UK it's a (fairly technical) term for relatively flat crockery, i.e. plates and saucers rather than cups and bowls. http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/flatware

Answer (score 1):

So there are a couple options for a phrase to describe disposable cutlery, without the word disposable.

One options is to call it a cutlery kit, this of course usually has multiple utensils, such as a fork, knife, spoon, napkin, and sometimes salt & pepper.

A second option is to call it plastic cutlery.

Here's a reference that refers to both of those options:  https://www.restaurantsupplydrop.com/collections/utensils

Answer (score 0):

"Disposable" "Throw-away" source:  http://skoozeme.com/issues/dontbus.html

[edit] "single use"  The term is used in Seattle's "compostables" law and California's proposed "no forced straws" law.   I guess anything's "disposable" with a large enough landfill!

"Party" does not describe this because (unless one has no access to durable tableware or is just being cheap) the "partyware" would be durable tableware.

Answer (score -1):

I believe the word you are looking for is "Consumables".

Comment: Hi Kenevil, welcome to EL&U. This isn't a bad start, but it's too short: the system has flagged it as "low-quality because of its **length** and **content**." An answer on EL&U is expected to be *authoritative, detailed, and explain why it is correct*. It's best if you [edit] your answer to provide more information - e.g., add a published definition of *consumables* (linked to the source) and say why it suits the context. You could even add an etymology, some published examples or a Google Ngram! For further guidance, see [answer] and take the EL&U **[Tour]**. :-)